# Rest API Parameters are received as null

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

Apex class -

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/account')

global class createAccount 
{    

    @HttpPost
    global static void createAcc() 
    {

        //-- Data coming from request
        String strFirstName = RestContext.request.params.get('First_Name');
        String strLastName = RestContext.request.params.get('Last_Name');
        String strPhone = RestContext.request.params.get('Phone');
        String strEmail = RestContext.request.params.get('Email');
        String strTitle = RestContext.request.params.get('Title');

        system.debug('RestContext.request.params: '+RestContext.request.params);

        system.debug('First_Name: '+strFirstName);
        system.debug('Last_Name: '+strLastName);
        system.debug('Phone: '+strPhone);
        system.debug('Email: '+strEmail);
        system.debug('Title: '+strTitle);
   }
}
```

When I check the debug log, the last debug statement shows null value.

12:17:31.033 (33840000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|RestContext.request.params: {Email=abc@gmail.com, First_Name=FirstName, Last_Name=LastName, Phone=+1234567890, ​**Title=Mr**}
12:17:31.033 (33886000)|USER_DEBUG|[23]|DEBUG|First_Name: FirstName
12:17:31.033 (33929000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|Last_Name: LastName
12:17:31.033 (33963000)|USER_DEBUG|[25]|DEBUG|Phone: +1234567890
12:17:31.033 (33998000)|USER_DEBUG|[26]|DEBUG|Email: abc@gmail.com
12:17:31.034 (34035000)|USER_DEBUG|[27]|DEBUG|Title: **null**

POST https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/account?First_Name=FirstName&Last_Name=LastName&Phone=+1234567890&Email=abc@gmail.com&​Title=Mr

Comment: How are you calling your REST endpoint?

Comment: JavaScript's encodeURIComponent replaces @ with %40, so the first thing to try would be to replace that character in the URI you post to see if that is the problem (i.e. your test URI is incorrectly encoded). Though weird that your first debug output looks correct.

Comment: As a starting point, I recreated you class and request. Using the dev console the output was properly displayed. Check to ensure your URL you are creating does not include and special characters before Title. Your paste also seems to strip off the Title=Mr in the URL. Again, recreating and calling from the dev console works just fine

Comment: @Swati  i tried your code and its working as expected.I am getting correct value for all the debugs including title.I think u must check your log again .There seems to be no issue.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. Recreating the URL worked. 3 special characters were included before Title in encoded URL. But the weird thing is the first debug statement output is correct !!

Comment: @Swati, well the debug was correct, it was part of the URL parameters. The issue was when you were trying to get it from the map, it did not exist because you were not including the additional characters

Comment: @Eric - looks like you had the solution, at your convenience, post as answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because old question the op has abandoned

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, I recreated you class and request. Using the dev console the output was properly displayed. Check to ensure your URL you are creating does not include and special characters before Title. Your paste also seems to strip off the Title=Mr in the URL. Again, recreating and calling from the dev console works just fine